# Issues using backspace on fields that are controlled by var num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

Tags: javascript

I apologize in advance if this happens to be a duplicated question.

I have recently started to play with auto-formatting certain fields for our warehouse CRM application to support the standardization of data.  All our forms are specific to US-based areas, so the phone numbers should be (123)-456-7890, obviously most people aren't going to put in the effort to make sure this data is always the same across each entry, I'm using the below JavaScript function to control the data (I did not design the function).

```
<script>
    function phoneMask() {
        var num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
        $(this).val('(' + num.substring(0, 3) + ')' + '-' + num.substring(3, 6) + '-' + num.substring(6, 10));
    }
    $('[type="tel"]').keyup(phoneMask);
</script>
```

This works fantastically when entering a phone number, but causes a small annoyance when REMOVING data from the same field.  if someone simply uses the BACKSPACE key, they are able to delete 7890, and then either have to HOLD the BACKSPACE key for a about 1.5sec to make the cursor go past the - to 456, or you have to manually move the house behind the -.

I am curious if there is something I can add to this function to help clear the auto-entered `( ) - -` characters, or maybe if there's a way replace function can be altered to account for having to remove the data.

Thanks in advance!

So far I have tried googling similar questions/situations with little to no luck.  This isn't an emergency to find a way around the above issue, it just makes it annoying for the data entry staff who spend a lot of time on the forms with this data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't look like plain JS, but jQuery.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's true, although I don't think it's relevant. It should work exactly the same if you use the analogous vanilla JS functions.

Comment: Except for the `this` binding, which behaves differently from plain JS in jQuery event handlers.

Comment: The problem is that your code adds `-` characters even if the user hasn't filled in that part of the number. So they delete the `-` and then it adds it back.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't think so. I'm pretty sure `addEventListener()` binds `this` to the event target.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: looks like you're right, for some reason I thought it was the global context for plain JS.

Comment: You mention that you are starting to auto format specific fields. You could always take advantage of an existing plugin that will handle all of the heavy lifting for you. Here is a minimally sized plugin http://vanilla-masker.github.io/vanilla-masker/

Comment: I suggest you use an input masking plugin, they handle these things for you. I also think `type="tel"` will make the browser display formatting characters like this.